# Adding and removing classes with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

So I'm trying to make puzzle pieces appear and disappear using JavaScript, or any other method that doesn't include refreshing the page.

The way that I'm looking to do this, is simply by adding the class "disableMenu" to the table rows(the puzzle pieces are constructed using an HTML table, it's super easy that way).

So basically what I've tried to do, is add IDs to the table rows, and using this JavaScript to try to remove the class from them. It obviously didn't work.

```
$('table > 1').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('disableMenu').siblings().removeClass('disableMenu');
});

$(document).click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('table').length > 0) return;
    $('ul > li').removeClass('disableMenu');
});
```

That's the JScript that I'm trying to use, and this is my complete HTML document.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
   <head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <title>Complete the puzzle!</title>
      <style>
         .disableMenu {
         display: none;
         }
         .merge {
         position:absolute;
         left: 496px;
         top: 5px;
         }
         .merge0 {
         position:absolute;
         left:300px;
         top:4px;
         }
         .merge1 {
         position:absolute;
         top: 218px;
         left: 530px;

         }
         .merge2 {
         position:absolute;
         top: 218px;
         left: 688px;
         }
         .row1 {
         position:absolute;
         left: 301px;
         top: 208px;
         }
         .row2 {
         position:absolute;
         top: 476px;
         left: 301px;
         margin:0;
         }
         .row3 {
         position:absolute;
         top: 495px;
         left: 716px;
         margin:0;
         }
         .row4 {
         position:absolute;
         top: 691px;
         left: 300px;
         margin:0;
         }
      </style>
   <body style="

      ">

    <script>

    $('table > 1').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('disableMenu').siblings().removeClass('disableMenu');
});

$(document).click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('table').length > 0) return;
    $('ul > li').removeClass('disableMenu');
});

    </script>
      <div>
         <table id="table" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
            <tr id="1">
               <td>
                  <img  src="1.png" class="merge0">
               </td>
               <td>
                  <img id="2" src="6.png" class="merge">
               </td>
               <td>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <img src="4.png" class="row1">
               </td>
               <td id="gone">
                  <img src="2.png" class="merge1 disableMenu">
               </td>
               <td>
                  <img src="7.png" class="merge2">
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <img src="8.png" class="row2">
               </td>
               <td>
                  <img src="5.png" class="row3">
               </td>
               <td>
                  <img src="3.png" class="row4 disableMenu">
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </div>
      <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
      <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
      <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
   </body>
   </head>
</html>
```

(Sorry for the size of that code, I didn't know exactly how much of it was relevant).

Any help would be appreciated. Eventually, I'd like it so that when someone visits a URL, it will automatically reveal a puzzle piece. For now though, I just want it to be implemented however is possible.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I'm just not going to do it, I'm stumped. Thanks for the effort, though!

Comment: `> 1` means what? You a `<1>` element?

Comment: `table > 1` won't match anything. If you're trying to match the `tr` with `id="1"`, you'll want `table > #1`. Of course, since IDs are unique, `#1` will be sufficient. Or are you trying to match something else?

Comment: @PaulRoub I'm trying to change the class on that unique <tr>. So if I changed `table > 1` into `table > #1`, it should be functional?

EDIT: Gosh, I'm stupid. I meant that I'm trying to change that unique <td>, not the <tr>

Comment: To be honest I think you're going about this in completely the wrong manner. You should be looking at replacing the hidden puzzle piece with the revealed one not trying to uncover an existing piece. Also for the record this won't be even kind of secure doing it in JS only, even a moderately knowledgeable person could reveal the whole puzzle easily. You could look at this for a starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/aufrnag9/

Comment: Wrap your onclick in a document.ready()

Comment: @RickCalder It's not like I'm going to be using this seriously.. I'm trying to learn JavaScript, not secure a company's sacred puzzle.

Comment: Okay, just wanted you to understand the limitations of JS that's all.

Comment: Yeah, I get it. But seriously, a "moderately knowledgeable" person wouldn't be posting this question in the first place. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You completely misunderstood what I was trying to say, and you'd be amazed some of the questions people ask to do things they don't understand aren't secure. lol

That aside, here's a bit of a mix of your idea and what I said earlier, this might get you on the way? http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/aufrnag9/1/

Comment: @RickCalder So if I somehow implement `$(".cover").on("click",function(){
    $(this).css("background","transparent");
});`, and tweak ".cover" and edit it so it works with my code, it should be functional?

Comment: To be honest I'm getting a little confused about what it is you're trying to do. Are you trying to reveal the puzzle pieces as you click the covering piece? If so then yes, modifying my code to your code will work. Don't even bother with the toggling classes, just modify the CSS of the covering piece.

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to do is make it so that when a URL is reached, it uncovers a piece. But seeing as I'm clueless, I'd just like it so that when I click on the piece, it'll reveal, and I can work on the extras later.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the script tag in the bottom of the body after  div ends or add the code in

```
$(document).ready();
```